# How to avoid sparks over the load at high voltages?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, circuit-design, constant-current, spark

I built a constant current source:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSvI1t.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When connecting SW1 it use to spark over SW1 contacts because output of OA1 was always clipped to positive rail, so I added OA2 to raise the OA1 inverting input to a higher value than non-inverting input. now output of OA1 is clipped to negative rail until SW1 is connected. I also slowed down OA1 using R1 and C1.

With OA2 added to the circuit there's no sparks when connecting SW1 but a spark happens when disconnecting SW1.

Why a spark happens when disconnecting SW1 and is there anyway to avoid disconnecting spark?

Comment: Any line length in the loop current causes L=10nH/cm approx and V=LdI/dt with dt going to zero on a dry switch. so not possible unless you add a plastic cap across contacts, then it will oscillate and decay, so it must handle this ripple current. switches of this magnitude are like starter solenoids with a large air gap.

Comment: Please show where the op-amp power supplies are connected.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Can that spark damage the load? an LED for example?

Comment: @Andyaka Added the supply to the schematic.

Comment: Yes overvoltage can damage LEDs rated at -5V per LED, which is why flyback protection is needed as the flyback is always with reverse voltage.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 What should I do then? should I pull down the mosfet gate manually before disconnecting the load to avoid sparks? is there a better way?

Comment: That’s a good way if the built-in diode can handle the clamp current.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main load supply is 400 volts and your circuit attempts to deliver a constant current feed to the load hence, as you open SW1, the MOSFET is driven hard (at that precise moment) to try and force a current into the load despite the SW1 contacts opening. This creates a spark and, it seems to me, that if it didn't create a spark then it wouldn't be a good constant current generator.

It seems that your are trying to counteract something that is a desired feature of a constant current generator. It's a similar story when closing the SW1 contacts.

Comment: It makes perfect sense, thank you. even though it happens in milli-seconds, is it possible that forced current (and increased voltage) for that very brief moment damage the load?

Comment: The load current is being regulated by the circuit so it shouldn't know that there is a spark at all. The MOSFET will take the brunt of the stress and not the load.

Comment: Last question; even with OA2 circuitry and a huge capacitor for the integrator I still see a very small and weak spark when closing SW1. it causes for example an LED to dimly turn on for a short time, turn off, and then slowly turn on. there's an overshoot in this circuit, what might be the cause of it?

Comment: I don't see the LED in the circuit in your question.

Comment: An LED instead of RL.

Comment: I think you should consider simulating the design to see what might be causing this. I can't see a mechanism.